# How to sort according to time in array of Object?

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, momentjs

I have an array of object such as

```
[{
  time: "13:20",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}, {
  time: "13:40",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}, {
  time: "04:20",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}]
```

and I want them to sort according to time. I did some research on momentjs but I didn't found something useful.

The main problem I am facing is How to convert that time that I am getting into String format to some comparable format for sorting. Any kind of help will be appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Do you always have `hour:minute` formatted strings ?

Answer (score 3):

You make a same date for all the times. And then `getTime()` and compare that

```js
let arr = [{
  time: "13:20",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}, {
  time: "13:40",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}, {
  time: "04:20",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}]

const toTime = (t) => new Date(`December 17, 1995 ${t}`).getTime();


arr.sort((a,b) => toTime(a.time) - toTime(b.time))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your time strings are in the `HH:MM` format, you can simply do a lexicographical sort with [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```js
const data = [
  { time: '13:20', key2: '', key3: '' },
  { time: '13:40', key2: '', key3: '' },
  { time: '04:20', key2: '', key3: '' },
  { time: '23:03', key2: '', key3: '' }
];

const ascending = [...data].sort((a, b) => a.time.localeCompare(b.time));
const descending = [...data].sort((a, b) => b.time.localeCompare(a.time));

console.log(JSON.stringify(ascending));
console.log(JSON.stringify(descending));
```

If your time strings do not follow this format, ie. may be specified as `H`, `HH`, `HH:M`, `HH:MM`..., then you can parse the string with [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```js
const data = [
  { time: '13:20', key2: '', key3: '' },
  { time: '13:40', key2: '', key3: '' },
  { time: '04:20', key2: '', key3: '' },
  { time: ' 4:25', key2: '', key3: '' },
  { time: '23:03', key2: '', key3: '' },
  { time: '14: 3', key2: '', key3: '' },
  { time: ' 2   ', key2: '', key3: '' },
];

const hourMinutes = str => /\s*(?<hh>\d*)\s*:?\s*(?<mm>\d*)\s*/.exec(str);
const toMinutes = ({ hh = 0, mm = 0 }) => (+hh) * 60 + (+mm);
const toTime = ({ time }) => toMinutes(hourMinutes(time).groups);

const ascending = [...data].sort((a, b) => toTime(a) - toTime(b));
const descending = [...data].sort((a, b) => toTime(b) - toTime(a));

console.log(JSON.stringify(ascending));
console.log(JSON.stringify(descending));
```

Comment: This approach assumes time value will be double digits. If you change `"04:20"` to `"4:20"`, this will fail

Comment: @Rajesh, you are right and this is why I added the assumption HH:MM in my answer, the OP time strings seem to be formatted like this

Comment: I have had quite a lot of issue with datetime value compared as string. Hence added a caveat.

Comment: @Rajesh, this is a totally valid point, I will edit my answer! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can take following approach to sort it:

#### Logic

- Create date object and add necessary time value you have.
- Sort it based on these date values.

Benefit of having date based approach is that it will handle all time value cases. I have updated data to have second values as well for demonstration

```js
var data = [{
  time: "13:20",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}, {
  time: "13:40",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}, {
  time: "04:20:10",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}, {
  time: "04:20:20",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}];

function getAddedTimeValue(time) {
  const parts = [...time.split(':'), 0, 0, 0, 0].slice(0, 4);
  const date = new Date();
  date.setHours.apply(date, parts);
  return date.getTime();
}

data.sort((a, b) => getAddedTimeValue(a.time) - getAddedTimeValue(b.time));

// For descending:
// data.sort((a, b) => getAddedTimeValue(b.time) - getAddedTimeValue(a.time));

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the first numeric part that is before `:` and compare that for sorting and if the first part is same, then consider the second numeric part that is after `:`

**Sort Ascending**

```js
var arr = [{
  time: "13:20",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}, {
  time: "13:40",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}, {
  time: "04:20",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aSplit = a.time.split(':');
  var bSplit = b.time.split(':');
  return (aSplit[0] - bSplit[0] || aSplit[1] - bSplit[1]);
});
console.log(arr);
```

**Sort Descending**

```js
var arr = [{
  time: "13:20",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}, {
  time: "13:40",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}, {
  time: "04:20",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
}];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aSplit = a.time.split(':');
  var bSplit = b.time.split(':');
  return (bSplit[0] - aSplit[0] || bSplit[1] - aSplit[1]);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get minutes of the given time and sort by this value.

```js
const getMinutes = s => s.split(':').reduce((h, m) => h * 60 + m);

var array = [{ time: "13:20", key2: "", key3: "" }, { time: "13:40", key2: "", key3: "" }, { time: "04:20", key2: "", key3: "" }];

array.sort((a, b) => getMinutes(a.time) - getMinutes(b.time));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could parse and sort the `time` field of each item in a custom callback passed to `Array#sort()` as shown below:

```js
const input = [ { time : "13:20" , key2: "", key3: ""},{ time : "13:40" , key2: "", key3: ""},{ time : "04:20" , key2: "", key3: ""}];


const output = input.sort((a, b) => {
  
  const [aHours, aMinutes] = a.time.split(':');
  const [bHours, bMinutes] = b.time.split(':');
  
  if(aHours < bHours) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if(aHours > bHours) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    
    if(aMinutes < bMinutes) {
      return -1;
    }
    else if(aMinutes > bMinutes) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  
  return 0; 
});

console.log(output);
```